# Is there a particular syntax for initializing an std::array from another, different std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, initialization

I've this situation:

```
class A {
    ...
};

class B {
    public:
        B(A x) { .... }
}

std::array<A, some_constant_value> init;
std::array<B, some_constant_value> arr = {
    init[0], 
    init[1],
    init[2],
    ...... ,
    init[some_constant_value-1]
};
```

Is there, by any chance, a better syntax than this to avoid typing all the elements down? ( And that won't require meddling in the off-chance that some_constant_value will change? )

Comment: Do you *need* initialization or can you take the easy route and do assignment?

Comment: @Pubby I can't do the assignment because B won't construct without an argument, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this code lying around. I think it's what you want:

```
  template<unsigned... Indices>
  struct indices {
    using next = indices<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)>;
  };

  template<unsigned N>
  struct build_indices {
    using type = typename build_indices<N-1>::type::next;
  };
  template<>
  struct build_indices<0> {
    using type = indices<>;
  };

  namespace impl {
    template<typename To, typename From, unsigned... Is>
    std::array<To, sizeof...(Is)>
    array_convert_impl(std::array<From, sizeof...(Is)> const& from, indices<Is...>) {
      return std::array<To, sizeof...(Is)>{{ from[Is]... }}; 
    }
  } // namespace impl
  template<typename To, typename From, unsigned N>
  std::array<To, N>
  array_convert(std::array<From, N> const& from) {
    return impl::array_convert_impl<To>(from, typename build_indices<N>::type());
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
std::array<B, some_constant_value> arr = array_convert<B>(init);
```

Comment: Holy smokes, it works! As soon as I understand the whole thing I'll accept this as an answer, thanks.

Comment: @Svalorzen Apologies for the lack of explanation. If you need help understanding some part then just ask.

Comment: You can reduce it a bit by removing the useless forward declaration of array_convert, removing the explicit cast to To (OP is doing implicit) and using `auto` in the example. A few words less should take a few seconds less to understand ;-)

Comment: @Pubby I think I got the general idea, though a more detailed explanation would be nice. I understand that `build_index` creates some sort of list of integers to access the original array which is then expanded, but I'm not sure how the recursive process works exactly.

Comment: @Pubby Moreover, can you tell me how safe it is to use this in general? Are there cases in which the compiler may not notice a wrong usage, and runtime crashes because of it? ( though I don't think so since it is expanded at compile time )

Comment: @Svalorzen: The key idea is that if `I...` is a pack of integers, then `std::get<I>(arr)...` (or equivalently `arr[I]...`) is a pack of array elements. So the vast majority of the code is concerned with building the pack of integers.

Comment: @Svalorzen It is pretty much equivalent to your original code so it can only crash if that code does. `build_index<5>` will give you a type `indices<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>` which can be deduced in `array_convert_impl`'s template parameter `Is` to be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. About the generation: it's important to know that `sizeof...(Indices)` is the number of variadic arguments, which would be 5 in this case.

Comment: @Pubby Thanks. The last thing I don't undertand is how does `build_indices` stack up all the intermediate results from `indices`.

Comment: @Svalorzen it creates a chain of `next`, maybe this will help: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4NXJ6apj (I manually expanded it over several steps)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution provided by the Standard Library is:

```
std::array<B, some_constant_value> 
arr((std::copy(init.begin(),init.end(),(&arr)->begin()),arr));
```

Note that the argument of the constructor is enclosed by `((...))`, so that it
is correctly parsed as a comma-expression rather than as two arguments.

This solution relies upon the fact that `B` is implicitly constructible from
`A`. A short solution that will also work if the converting constructor is
made explicit is:

```
auto lamb = 
[&init]() -> B { static size_t i = 0; return B(init[i++]); };  
std::array<B, some_constant_value> 
arr((std::generate((&arr)->begin(),(&arr)->end(),lamb),arr));
```

The following test program, built with GCC 4.7.2, clang 3.2 and Intel C++ 13.1.1,
(options `-g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11`) illustrates both solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

struct A 
{
    int _i = 42;
};

struct B 
{
    B(A x) 
    : _i(x._i){}
    int _i; 
};

struct C 
{
    explicit C(A x) 
    : _i(x._i){}
    int _i; 
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<A, 10> init;
    array<B, 10> arr((copy(init.begin(),init.end(),(&arr)->begin()),arr));
    cout << "arr contains..." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        cout << arr[i]._i << endl;
    }
    auto lamb = 
    [&init]() -> C { static size_t i = 0; return C(init[i++]); };  
    array<C, 10> brr((generate((&brr)->begin(),(&brr)->end(),lamb),brr));
    cout << "brr contains..." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < brr.size(); ++i) {
        cout << brr[i]._i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```